# Two cards are drawn from a well shuffled pack of $52$ cards. Find the probability that one of them is a red card and the other is a queen.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, solution-verification

> Two cards are drawn from a well shuffled pack of $52$ cards. Find the
> probability that one of them is a red card and the other is a queen.

**My Attempt**

The relevant cards are $26$ red cards and $2$ black queens i.e. in total $28$ cards.

I took four cases.

**Case 1 : One non-queen red card and one red queen**

The probability would be $$\frac{\binom{24}{1}\times\binom{2}{1}}{\binom{28}{2}}$$

**Case 2 : One non-queen red card and one black queen**

The probability would be $$\frac{\binom{24}{1}\times\binom{2}{1}}{\binom{28}{2}}$$

**Case 3 : Two red queens**

The probability would be $$\frac{\binom{2}{2}}{\binom{28}{2}}$$

**Case 4 : One red queen and one black queen**

The probability would be $$\frac{\binom{2}{1}\times\binom{2}{1}}{\binom{28}{2}}$$

So the required probability $$=\frac{48+48+1+4}{\binom{28}{2}}=\frac{101}{378}$$

Is the above solution correct?

Comment: Your answer is far too high.  You are claiming that there is a $26.7\%$ chance of this outcome, which is clearly false.  Just try it with a real deck of cards.

Comment: Why is your denominator $\binom {28}2$?  Nobody is promising you that both of the draws are "relevant".  Note also that, unless I am misreading the problem, drawing $\heartsuit Q, \,\spadesuit 5$ is a success, but you don't count such draws.

Comment: @lulu One card is red, and the *other card* is a queen.

Comment: @DanielMathias  Ah, thank you.  Missed that "other".

Comment: Building on what @Lulu points out, an estimate nearing 25% success, given that queens are only ~7% of the deck, and that success needs a queen within 2 draws (hard) and a red card (easy), should be enough to raise alerts about the initial solution. Note that the actual probability is just thousandths away from the likelihood of drawing a single queen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your answer can't be correct as you have taken the sample space as $28$ cards, whereas you are drawing from a full pack of $52$.

"one red card" does not exclude that card being a Queen, neither does "the other card is a Queen" exclude it being a red Queen. Also "one red card" doesn't necessarily mean first card,  so possible unordered selections are

- red Queen,red Queen
- red Queen,black Queen
- red non-queen,  Queen

Then, using the hypergeometric distribution (drawing without replacement)

$$Pr = \dfrac{\binom22 +\binom21\binom21+ \binom{24}1\binom41}{\binom{52}2}= \frac{101}{1326}$$

Comment: You wrote 101 instead of 102

Comment: @Gwen $1+4+96=101$

Comment: I see now. In my computation there are 2 times where 2 red queens appear in different order. Thanks @DanielMathias

Comment: So instead of taking $\binom{28}{2}$ in the denominator I should have taken $\binom{52}{2}$

Comment: @Maverick: That's right.

Answer (score 4):

One obvious problem with your solution is that you have $28 \choose 2$ as the denominator. You need to count all the possibilities, and that would be $52 \choose 2$.

---

Here's one way to solve this question. The requirements set by the question can be met through $3$ separate cases.

**Case 1.** Both cards are red

Clearly, one card must be a queen, the other can be anything. In other words, we can have two queens or one queen and one non-queen. So the probability for this case would be

$$\frac{{2 \choose 2} + {2 \choose 1} \times {24 \choose 1}}{{52 \choose 2}} = \frac{98}{{52 \times 51}}$$

**Case 2.** First card is red, second is black

The black card must be a queen, the red one can be anything. The probability would be

$$\frac{26}{52} \times \frac{2}{51} = \frac{52}{52 \times 51}$$

**Case 3.** First card is black, second is red

Again, the black card must be a queen, the red one can be anything. So the probability would be

$$\frac{2}{52} \times \frac{26}{51} = \frac{52}{52 \times 51}$$

The events are mutually exclusive, so we can add the probabilities to get the required probability.

$$\begin{align*} Pr &= \frac{98 + 52 + 52}{52 \times 51} \\[0.3cm]
&= \frac{101}{1326}
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Your first case counts drawing two red queens twice. You should have $\frac{\binom{2}{2}+\binom{2}{1}\times\binom{24}{1}}{\binom{52}{2}}$

Comment: @DanielMathias Corrected it. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The ideas presented here are really nice. They're taking each individual case and adding them up. I'm showing this with a singular concept, but requires a good idea of combination.

**Combination is based upon choosing or choice**

Let $E$ be the event of picking a queen and a red card

Here, You're trying to choose (rather pick, but it's the same logic) 2 cards out of 52. Hence total possible picks =$ \binom{52}{2}$

Now favourable picks are:-

1. *1 red card*

Possible picks = $ \binom {26}{1}$

2. *1 queen*

Possible picks= $ \binom {4}{1}$

It states *1 red card* **AND** *1 queen* which means the possible picks will be multiplied to get favourable outcomes=$\binom{26}{1} × \binom {4}{1}$

But we should notice, using this logic, the arrangement of 2 red queens appear twice,[Diamond Queen,Hearts queen] and [Hearts Queen, Diamond Queen]. But these are the same when they're taken as a collection. So we should **subtract 1** from total favourable outcomes

Hence $$P(E)= \frac{\binom{26}{1} × \binom {4}{1}-1}{\binom{52}{2}}= \frac{101}{1326} $$

Thanks @DanielMathias for pointing out my mistake